# Difference between true & pseudo random numbers

Tags: random-number-generation

I recently heard that in Linux, `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` are pseudo random number generators but not true random number generator.

So I am curious to know the difference between pseudo & true random number? In other words What is the difference between pseudo-randomness & true-randomness?

Comment: This could largely be answered by a Google search. Do you have a more specific question about this related to computational science?

Comment: @horchler If this question is more suitable on other (SE) site (example-Unix & Linux) then tell/suggest me

Comment: [Wikipedia article Pseudorandom number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator)

Answer (score 2):

Most random numbers are in fact pseudo-random: they use a seed that is fed to a perfectly deterministic algorithm which can then generate series of numbers which are periodic but with a **very large and complicated period** so they usually appear random.

This has drawbacks of course since it's not really random, but also advantages, among which is **reproducibility**: if you store the seed, using this seed again will give you the exact same list of "random" numbers...

Here are [a](https://www.christianpinder.com/articles/pseudo-random-number-generation/) [few](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) [links](http://engineering.mit.edu/ask/can-computer-generate-truly-random-number) as well as another to [a source of real random numbers](https://www.random.org/)

Comment: Conversely, for certain applications (generation of cryptographic keys, picking winning lottery numbers, etc.) it's very important that the output of a random number generator be unpredictable.  In cryptographic applications it's common to combine actual physically random numbers with a pseudorandom number generator to produce unpredicatable output.